# How to prevent backspace from deleting text in a disabled textArea in Edge browser?

Tags: html, textarea, microsoft-edge, disabled-input, backspace

There seems to be a bug in Edge browser with disabled textBoxes and textAreas.
I'm facing this issue in my App, **they accept the backspace (also delete key) and delete the text!**

I tried to use `e.preventDefault()` in keydown and keypress but it didn't work.

Any suggestions on how to workaround this bug?

**You can see the issue here (on Edge):**

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_textarea_disabled

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_text_disabled2

**Update:**

This issue seems to be fixed, but still not flighted according to this link

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/13396475/

But here's my workaround for now:

make it readonly with some css to make it look disabled, and use "return false;" to prevent the browser from going to previous page.

```
<textarea readonly onkeydown="return false;" style="background: #f1f1f1" >test .....</textarea>
```

Comment: There are a number of issue tickets already at the Edge feedback/bug site. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/?page=1&q=textarea%20disabled... you did not include your workaround code to cancel the keydown event.... onkeydown="return false;" should work.

Comment: @RobParsons this solution only works when input is not "disabled"

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in Edge browser, and `readonly` workaround can be also useful if needed